# How do I transform the incoming JSON payload having objects to a payload having a list of the objects expected by the downstream system

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

**input payload:**

```
{
  "9873452": "74298",
  "9067329": "32115"
  "1234556": "98765"
}
```

**Expected output payload**

```
{
    "provider": "Salesforce",
    "payload": [
        {
            "empId": 74298,
            "empName": "9873452"
        },
        {
            "empId": 32115,
            "empName": "9067329"
        },
        {
            "empId": 98765,
            "empName": "1234556"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with the below code to transform the same but not able to get the expected output payload

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
provider: "Salesforce",
payload:
 [empName: key,
empId:value]
})
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

Modified your dataweave below. Since you expect array in output, [pluck](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-pluck) will be useful here since output of [mapObject](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-mapobject) will still be an object whereas for pluck it will be an array

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"provider": "Salesforce",
"payload": payload pluck (value, key, index) -> 
 {
        "empName": key,
        "empId": value
    }
}
```